# What's the difference between <p>(.+?)<\/p> and (?<=<p>)(.+?)(?=<\/p>) in regex

Tags: regex

These two expressions match some elements different, I don't understand why.
The task is to match a text between `<p>` and `</p>`. But one test fails and I can not see it. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have for example such string: `asd<p>qwe</p>zxc`

The `<p>(.+?)<\/p>` will find:

```
<p>qwe</p>
```

And the 
`(?<=<p>)(.+?)(?=<\/p>)` will find:

```
qwe
```